# Reducing pixels in large data set (sklearn)

Tags: image-processing, scikit-learn, classification

Im currently working on a classification project but I'm in doubt about how I should start off.

**Goal**

Accurately classifying pictures of size 80*80 (so 6400 pixels) in the correct class (binary).

**Setting**

5260 training samples, 600 test samples

**Question**

As there are more pixels than samples, it seems logic to me to 'drop' most of the pixels and only look at the important ones before I even start working out a classification method (like SVM, KNN etc.).

Say the training data consists of X_train (predictors) and Y_train (outcomes). So far, I've tried looking at the *SelectKBest()* method from sklearn for feature extraction. But what would be the best way to use this method and to know how many k's I've actually got to select?

It could also be the case that I'm completely on the wrong track here, so correct me if I'm wrong or suggest an other approach to this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are suggesting to reduce the dimension of your feature space. That is a method of regularization to reduce overfitting. You haven't mentioned overfitting is an issue so I would test that first. Here are some things I would try:

1. Use transfer learning. Take a pretrained network for image recognition tasks and fine tune it to your dataset. Search for transfer learning and you'll find many resources.
2. Train a convolutional neural network on your dataset. CNNs are the go-to method for machine learning on images. Check for overfitting.
3. If you want to reduce the dimensionality of your dataset, resize the image. Going from 80x80 => 40x40 will reduce the number of pixels by 4x, assuming your task doesn't depend on fine details of the image you should maintain classification performance.

There are other things you may want to consider but I would need to know more about your problem and its requirements.